# Словарь на C++ как (Dictionary) на C#

Tags: c#, c++, память, производительность

На C# имеется удивительно быстрый словарь (Dictionary), хотелось бы узнать, а имеется ли такой же производительный только на C++ ? Пробовал `unordered_map`, `hash_map`, `map`, но производительность в разы ниже чем у `Dictionary` сишарповского...
P.S: Пара имеет вид `<unsigned int, unsigned int>`

Comment: > но производительность в разы ниже чем у Dictionary сишарповского

Мне кажется, вы что-то путаете.

Comment: Это действительно похоже на сказку ) но скорее всего я что-то делаю не правильно ... Если у вас есть код максимально быстро сохраняющий, ищущий и удаляющий такую пару <unsigned int, unsigned int>, то я был бы очень признателен )

Comment: Код и результаты замеров в студию. Иначе вброс.

Comment: @Dith: поскольку дефолтная аллокация в C++ медленнее, чем в .NET (heap lock и фсё такоэ), мне результаты ТС не кажутся такими уж подозрительными. Но да, хотелось бы цифры.

Comment: Кстати, дотнетовский Dictionary основан на HashMap, в то время как std::map в качестве несущей структуры данных использует красно-чёрное дерево.

Comment: @VladD очень интересное заявление про выделение памяти, можно поподробнее? а то гуглеж ничего не дает =(
ТС пробовал и unordered_map и hash_map, что есть таки хэш-таблицы.

Comment: @Dith: ну [смотрите](http://codebetter.com/stevehebert/2006/03/03/raw-memory-allocation-speed-c-vs-c/#comment-425). Обыкновенно heap в С++ устроен как связный список. Для выделения памяти используется какая-то из стратегий поиска по этому списку. На время поиска [берётся](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx), понятно, [глобальный lock](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4524437/276994).

Comment: @Dith:  C# же просто увеличивает текущий heap pointer, [пруф](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx):

>  ...by adding some integer to the pointer that we call “the stack pointer” or adding the same integer to the pointer that we call “the top of the GC heap”

Так что аллокация памяти в C# вполне может быть быстрее. Кроме того, не забудьте, что в тестовой программе на C++ деаллокация обычно происходит _быстро как только возможно_ (снова дополнительные расходы!), в то время как GC в C# может и вообще не запуститься.

Comment: @Dith: (сорри, на этом у меня лимит комментариев к вопросу [закончился](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/845/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).)

Comment: @VladD типичный искусственный тест, совершенно ничего не доказывающий. В примере для сишарп память фактически не выделяется. Стоит сказать спасибо за ссылки, будут полезны сюда заходящим.

Comment: @Dith, а не могли ли вы представить пример более корректного кода ?

Answer (score 60):

На самом деле, сравнение языков — штука неблагодарная. Всегда найдутся тесты, на которых один из языков выиграет по сравнению с другим, и всегда найдутся люди, считающие, что данный тест не релевантен и подобный код никогда не будет встречаться в реальности.

Тем не менее, я бы не сказал, что результаты ТС очень уж неожиданны: в .NET действительно выделение памяти обычно происходит быстрее, чем в нативных языках без кастомного аллокатора. А небольшие тесты обычно гораздо больше нагружают аллокатор чем, скажем, механизмы вызова функций.

Причиной такой разницы в производительности аллокатора является то, что объекты C++ невозможно перемещать в памяти, а значит, привычный алгоритм выделения памяти (который, как известно, поддерживает список свободных блоков, и ищет подходящий при аллокации) работает довольно медленно, и, хуже того, требует глобальной блокировки памяти (что ещё более ухудшает ситуацию в многопоточном сценарии). Кроме того, объекты в C++ имеют тенденцию освобождаться быстро как только можно, что приводит к дополнительной нагрузке на *освобождение* памяти, которое тоже требует глобальную блокировку.

В среде .NET же всё происходит по-другому. Объекты всегда выделяются на вершине heap-памяти, а значит, выделение не медленнее, чем `InterlockedIncrement`. .NET'у не нужно поддерживать список свободных блоков потому, что при сборке мусора происходит компактификация heap-памяти: объекты перемещаются, заполняя «дыры».

---

Кроме того, известия о том, что код на C++ вполне может быть медленнее аналогичного кода на C#, давно не новость. Вот, например, замечательная [серия статей](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-chineseenglish-dictionary-reader) о простом приложении от мастеров нативного программирования, и [резюме](https://blog.codinghorror.com/on-managed-code-performance-again/) Джефа Этвуда:

> Чтобы обойти по производительности версию на C#, Реймонду пришлось написать собственные процедуры ввода-вывода, переписать класс `string`, воспользоваться кастомным аллокатором, а также собственной процедурой отображения кодовых страниц.

Это подтверждается и бенчмарком, который приведён ниже: нативные контейнеры «из коробки» существенно проигрывают дотнетовским, (некоторые) самописные контейнеры выигрывают.

---

Теперь самое интересное: измерения.

C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int seed = 1;

            var timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                seed = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223;
                dict.Add(seed, i);
            }

            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(
                "elapsed time = {0} ms, dictionary entries count = {1}",
                timer.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                dict.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

C++:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    map<int, int> dict;
    int seed = 1;

    auto begin = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        seed = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223;
        dict.insert(make_pair(seed, i));
    }

    auto end = clock();

    double elapsedMs = double(end - begin) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "elapsed time = " << elapsedMs
         << " ms, dictionary entries count = " << dict.size()
         << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Результаты измерений (release mode, 5 запусков подряд без отладчика):

C#

> elapsed time = 1138 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 1127 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 1133 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 1134 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 1129 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000

C++

> elapsed time = 8377 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 8408 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 8377 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 8377 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000
> elapsed time = 8361 ms, dictionary entries count = 10000000

Среднее время: C# = 1132 мс, C++ = 8379 мс.

Я не утверждаю, что мои тесты идеальны. Кроме того, они релевантны лишь на моём компьютере. Если кто-то предложит лучшую методику измерения, я с удовольствием применю её тоже. Тем не менее, в моих условиях производительность `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` на добавление элементов существенно превосходит производительность `std::map`.

---

Обратите внимание, что `Dictionary` использует хэш-таблицы, в то время как `std::map` в моей имплементации использует красно-чёрное дерево в качестве несущей структуры данных. Хэш-таблицы обычно сами по себе быстрее, так что скорость аллокации — не единственная причина лучшей скорости у `Dictionary`.

---

Замена в C++ `make_pair(seed, i)` на `pair<int, int>(seed, i)` по совету @igumnov не привела к большому отличию: 8361/8392/8361/8408/8361/8345.

---

Замена в C++ `std::map` на `std::unordered_map` по совету @Котик привела к значительному ускорению: 2230/2230/2230/2230/2246 (среднее 2233). Тем не менее, C++ всё ещё почти вдвое медленнее.

---

Заменил в C++ `std::unordered_map` на uthash по совету @igumnov. Результат немного хуже, чем `std::unordered_map`: 2963/2932/2948/2948/2932. Код:

```cpp
void testUhash()
{
    struct myint
    {
        int key;
        int value;
        UT_hash_handle hh;
    };

    struct myint* dict = NULL;
    int seed = 1;

    auto begin = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        seed = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223;
        struct myint* ps = (struct myint*)malloc(sizeof(struct myint));
        ps->key = seed;
        ps->value = i;
        HASH_ADD_INT(dict, key, ps);
    }

    auto end = clock();

    double elapsedMs = double(end - begin) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "elapsed time = " << elapsedMs
         << " ms, dictionary entries count = " << HASH_COUNT(dict)
         << endl;
}
```

---

Добавил `capacity = 10000000` в C++ и для честного сравнения в C# тоже. Изменения:

C++:

```cpp
unordered_map<int, int> dict(10000000);
```

C#:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>(10000000);
```

Действительно, стало скорее:

- C++: 1826/1856/1857/1841/1825, среднее 1841
- C#: 790/786/801/790/791, среднее 792

По-прежнему C# более чем вдвое впереди.

---

По совету @KoVadim убрал вычисление `seed` (capacity оставил), теперь рабочий цикл таков:

C++:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    //seed = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223;
    dict.insert(pair<int, int>(i, i));
}
```

C#:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    //seed = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223;
    dict.Add(i, i);
}
```

Результаты:

- C++: 1498/1514/1498/1498/1498, среднее 1501
- C#: 129/129/135/133/132, среднее 132

---

По совету @igumnov добавил в бенчмарк khash. Код:

```cpp
KHASH_MAP_INIT_INT(32, int)
void testKhash()
{
    int seed = 1;

    khiter_t iter;
    khash_t(32)* dict = kh_init(32);
    int dummy;
    
    auto begin = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        seed = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223;
        iter = kh_put(32, dict, seed, &dummy);
        kh_value(dict, iter) = i;
    }

    auto end = clock();

    double elapsedMs = double(end - begin) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "elapsed time = " << elapsedMs
         << " ms, dictionary entries count = " << kh_size(dict)
         << endl;
}
```

Результат: 577/577/608/577/577, среднее 583, массивный вин для нативного кода. Напомню, что лучший результат стандартного .NET-контейнера — 792 мс.

Кто предложит кастомный контейнер под .NET?

---

Попробовал имплементацию для .NET [`FastDictionary`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mapreduce-net/source) (проект [MapReduce.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121172200/https://code.google.com/p/mapreduce-net/)). Получилось немного медленнее, чем встроенный `Dictionary`: 853/865/842/841/842, среднее 849.

---

Попробовал скорость чистой аллокации для проверки гипотезы @Dith: 10 миллионов раз запускается конструктор пустого класса. Код:

C#:

```cs
static class Allocation
{
    class Foo
    {
    }

    static public void Test()
    {
        const int size = 10000000;
        var timer = new Stopwatch();

        timer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            new Foo();
        }
        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("elapsed time = {0} ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

C++:

```cpp
void testAlloc()
{
    const int size = 10000000;

    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
        exit(1);

    double freq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    auto begin = li.QuadPart;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        new Foo();

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    auto end = li.QuadPart;

    double elapsedMs = double(end - begin) / freq;
    cout << "elapsed time = " << elapsedMs
         << " ms" << endl;
}
```

Результаты:

- C#: 58/54/28/55/55 (среднее 50)
- C++: 407.719/400.693/401.674/401.926/399.976 (среднее 402.4)

Comment: А если так попробовать заменить?

    dict.insert(make_pair(seed, i));

    dict.insert (std::pair<int,int>(seed,i));

Comment: @VladD, хороший, наглядный тестбенч! +1  
Раз уж Вы начали эксперименты, а словами уже объяснили причину, то для наглядности можно бы было еще тест  на `С++` с аллокатором показать, который 10 млн. выделит заранее.

Comment: @mega: Спасибо! Я не спец по кастомным аллокаторам, напишете код? Я добавлю в ответ.

Comment: И еще я знаю одну нестандартную хэш таблицу. Может она окажется более быстрой. 
http://troydhanson.github.com/uthash/
Больше тестов хороших и разных.

Comment: Забенчмаркайте еще `std::unordered_map` -- так, наверно, более честно будет.

Comment: @igumnov: по идее, разницы не должно быть, оптимизатор заинлайнит `make_pair`. Проверил, вот новый результат: 8361/8392/8361/8408/8361/8345.

Comment: проверил с unordered_map. ускорение порядка в три раза по сравнению с map вариантом.

Если добавить в конструкторе кол-во элементов, то ещё в два раза быстрее.

Comment: @Котик, @KoVadim: подтверждаю, обновил ответ. У меня даже большее ускорение: ~3,75.

Comment: поправьте объявление на такое

    unordered_map<int, int> dict(10000000);

это как раз и даст ещё в два раза. Специально посмотрел на вызовы malloc/free - в оригинальном коде их миллионы. и собственно они съедают все.

Comment: @Котик: load_factor? Объясните для нуба попроще.

Comment: >напишете код? Я добавлю в ответ.

Уже начал, но @KoVadim Вам как раз предложил равнозначную альтернативу с конструктором :)

Comment: @KoVadim: добавил бенчмарк с capacity.

Comment: Ну, думаю - достаточно. И так понятно, что если дальше искать равные условия, то оба варианта будут примерно равны. Там уже пойдет гонка производительности, далекая от исходного алгоритма.

Comment: если вывести в с++ коде кол-во корзин и сколько элементов на корзину, то как раз и будет понятно, почему в два раза. (половина корзин пустая). если заполнять так, что seed = i, то скорость подымается ещё в три раза.

Можно долго спорить, кто быстрее, но просто для данной задачи реализация в С# оказалась более удачной. для других задач может быть наоборот. Поэтому контейнеров так много. Нужно точно выбирать под задачу, а не использовать универсальный на все случаи жизни.

Итого в конечном счете упираемся в выделение памяти.

Comment: Вот еще одна C++ хэш таблица. Автор уверяет что она бьет по скорости все что существовало до нее. Давайте тоже воткнем ее в тесты вдруг она все таки побьет C#

Пример использования.
http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/implementing-generic-hash-library-in-c/

Код:
https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/khash.h

Бенчмарк автора:
http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/comparison-of-hash-table-libraries/

Comment: @KoVadim: Сделал `seed = i`, скорость не упала :(. А как подобрать параметры, при которых C++ будет лучше? Я взял стандартный контейнер для обоих языков, есть какие-то более продвинутые, или надо писать самому?

Comment: В этой задаче есть одна скрытая штука, о которой забывают и которую сложновато померить правильно. В свое время у меня было соревнование, которое можно сказать, где быстрее FIFO очередь - с++ vs java. На маленьких тестах java рвала в раза 3-4. Но я ничего не изменяя, просто попросил оставить код в продакшн серверах на пару дней. И когда через код прошли сотни миллионов объектов, выяснилось, что мой код (который к тому же был скомпилирован без оптимизаций) ел в 18 раз меньше памяти и обработал в пару раз больше данных. Тесты потом повторялись много раз и результат был тот же. А причина - в GC.

Comment: @VladD я думаю, Вы не правы в описании способа выделения памяти. Рантайм С/С++ не заводит никаких списков, он просто вызывает HeapAlloc. A уже внутри (в куче) все эти списки и поиск по ним. Джит дотнета в свою очередь должен пользоваться чем то вроде HeapAlloc/VirtualAlloc (где же ему еще память брать). Однако по дороге от new до API происходит гораздо больше манипуляций. А посему чистое выделение памяти у С# быстрее быть не может.  
В тесте С++ время мерить лучше через QueryPerformanceCounter как аналог Stopwatch. Это не критично, но так опять же честнее).

Comment: @igumnov: добавил khash, обновил ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim: Понял вас. Сможете написать тест, провоцирующий GC? Я добавлю в бенчмарк.

Comment: @Dith: ну замените в моём описании `malloc`/`new` на `HeapAlloc` для Windows, проблема-то остаётся? Сейчас перелезу на `QueryPerformanceCounter`, отпишусь если результаты будут существенно отличаться.

Comment: @Merlin: спасибо!

Comment: @VladD это как раз ничего не изменит.  
Имеем голый HeapAlloc http://pastebin.com/VmJeepqm  
HeapAlloc + оверхэд от управления памятью http://pastebin.com/FqNYLrXm
Хотя в контексте вопроса это уже значения не имеет, раз опытным путем выяснили что дело не в выделении памяти.

Comment: Еще нужно по хорошему как-то потребление памяти измерить для полноты картины.

Comment: Спасибо, друзья. Такого расширенного ответа я не ожидал...

Comment: @KoVadim: Java в этом отношении хуже, потому что в ней для вставки в контейнер `int` боксируется в `Integer`. В C# с "настоящими" генериками, без type erasure, в Dictionary используется честный `int` и нагрузка на аллокатор и соответственно GC существенно меньше.

Comment: @Dith: а где результаты вашего бенчмарка? И да, в .NET выделяется большая арена и кешируется, так что HeapAlloc будет вызван редко.

Comment: Добавил ссылки на аналогичные измерения, на этот раз от Реймонда Чена и Рико Мариани.

Comment: @VladD бенчмарк можно не делать, если есть теоретическое обоснование ;) Я тоже думал что там должен быть свой менеджер, однако  
Вот мои результаты (Core i3, 8Gb RAM)
C++: 477.175/472.611/476.050/465.811/478.769 среднее 474.0832
С# : 1216/1192/1213/1180/1197 среднее 1216
Думаю разница в массивах не должна столь различна, чтобы существенно влиять на время, просто не знаю как еще можно избежать оптимизации и заставить выделять память.

Comment: @Dith: бенчмарк таки нужно делать :-) Вот мой код ([C#](http://pastebin.com/UYEPimFF), [C++](http://pastebin.com/zvzMBAiz)), результаты: (C#) 58/54/28/55/55, (C++) 407.719/400.693/401.674/401.926/399.976.

Comment: >бенчмарк таки нужно делать :-) Вот мой код (C#, C++), результаты...

@VladD, это лучше вынести в ответ, только расписать словами, что это ключевая разница, которая и влияет на результат, а то, без погружения в код, не всем будет ясно.

Comment: @mega: кнопка "ответить ещё раз" не фунционирует :( Смысл кода -- просто N раз вызван конструктор пустого класса (в C++ это memory leak, да). Добавил в основной ответ.

Comment: @VladD в вашем коде на C# тот-же принципиальная ошибка: ПАМЯТЬ ФАКТИЧЕСКИ НЕ ВЫДЕЛЯЕТСЯ из за оптимизации, можно хоть бесконечно крутить этот цикл памяти ни байта не выделется!  
Потому вы сравниваете ПУСТОЙ цикл фор с циклом, в котором выделение таки есть. Хватит уже выдавать желаемое за действительное.

Comment: Думаю тут все дело в реализации. На линуксе (AMD FX8320) работает в два раза быстрее чем под виндой. Тут подробно описывается сравнение [G++ vs MSVC](http://marknelson.us/2011/11/28/vc-10-hash-table-performance-problems/).

Comment: Так-же добавлю, что этот код с указателями (не смотря на свой недостаток) работает несколько быстрее чем код на стеке http://pastebin.com/WX1kSb3V Без цикла очистки памяти будет еще быстрее :)

Comment: Друзья, а не подскажите, как на C++ создать аналог шарпавского Dictionary<Type, List<float>>? Для встроенной системы, т.е. быстродействие тоже важно.

Answer (score 5):

Продолжение весьма интересной дискуссии:

как сказал [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), дотнетовский Dictionary основан на HashMap, так вот

> Самая неудачная реализация функции
> GetHashCode в .NET Framework – это
> реализация, используемая по умолчанию
> в структурах. Дело в том, что эта
> функция для структур делает следующее.
> Она с помощью рефлексии перебирает все
> поля и пытается получить хэш-код.
> Найдя первое поле, от которого можно
> получить хэш-код, функция завершает
> свою работу, возвращая это значение. В
> большинстве случаев она возвращает
> хэш-код первого попавшегося поля.
> Однако если структура состоит из
> ссылочных типов, и все они установлены
> в null, то функция по аналогии с
> классом возвращает порядковый номер
> объекта.
>
> ....
>
> У такого подхода есть два недостатка.
> Первое – такой хэш-код может оказаться
> и часто оказывается некорректным, так
> как по одному полю тяжело
> идентифицировать всю структуру.
> Во-вторых, **из-за использования
> рефлексии этот способ далек от
> идеальной производительности**.
> Поэтому при необходимости получения
> хэш-значений от структур, лучше
> реализовать соответствующие функции
> самостоятельно.

[источник](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/collections.xml)

[[@igumnov](/users/7053/igumnov)](/users/7053/igumnov) По поводу замеров памяти, есть хорошая статья "[Обработка больших объемов данных в памяти на C#](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114495/)"

Comment: Насчёт реализации `GetHashCode` святая правда. Рефлексия довольно тяжела. У меня есть, однако, подозрение, что для базовых типов есть оптимизация. А для кастомных структур `GetHashCode` неплохо бы, конечно, заимплементировать вручную.

Comment: Хм, судя по всему, в .NET 4 функция GetHashCode поменялась.

Тест:

    class HashTest
    {
        struct Test { public int x; public int y; }

        public static void Run()
        {
            Т(new Test() { x = 1, y = 2 });
            Т(new Test() { x = 1, y = 100 });
            Т(new Test() { x = 200, y = 2 });
        }

        static void Т(Test t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}, hash = {2}, hash({0}) = {3}, hash({1}) = {4}",
                              t.x, t.y, t.GetHashCode(), t.x.GetHashCode(), t.y.GetHashCode());
        }
    }

Comment: Результат:

> x = 1, y = 2, hash = 1745183319, hash(1) = 1, hash(2) = 2  
> x = 1, y = 100, hash = 1745183281, hash(1) = 1, hash(100) = 100  
> x = 200, y = 2, hash = 1745183390, hash(200) = 200, hash(2) = 2

Comment: Тем не менее, для тех, кто будет самостоятельно имплементировать `GetHashCode`, вот [полезная статья](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).

Comment: @VladD забавный факт: реализация `GetHashCode` поменялась - но реализация `Equals` осталась прежней!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вспомним, что у map первый параметр - тип ключа, второй - тип значения. 
Вы в каждой записи добавляете ключ 
seed = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223;
где seed = 1 постоянно. 
Соответственно, передается отдно и то-же значение ключа, что является наихудшим значением для вставки.

Во-вторых, и самое главное.
map эффективен для поиска значения по ключу и очень неэффективен при добавлении-удаления элементов.
Ваш же тест делает только добавление. Основные затраты при таком тесте - не аллокация, а добавление в дереве (красно-черном, как вы правильно заметили).
Если вы хотите сравнить dictionnary в дотнете и map в stl, вам необходимо написать тест, в котором сначала заполняются значения, а потом измерять время доступа к случайным значениям в цикле.
Если вам в приложении нужно часто искать значения - используем map, но тогда и тест пишем другой. Если вам нужно часто и много добавлять значения - используем vector, если добавлять/удалять - list. Тогда и тест (для добавления) будет другой:

```
vector<int> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    vec.push_back(i);
}
```

Ваш код для 1000000 элементов выполняется у меня 8386 ms, пример с вектором - 251 мс., в 33 раза быстрее.

Comment: Вы отвечаете на вопрос или на ответ? :)

Comment: (Ну и попробуйте пройти код в отладчике, увидите, что seed меняется.)

Comment: 1. Замечания к вопросу о неправомерности тестирования. 2. Да, вы правы. Облажался. seed меняется. Интересный алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

Напишу здесь, так как мой лимит коментариев кончился

> > Попробовал скорость чистой аллокации для проверки гипотезы [@Dith](/users/8139/dith): 10 миллионов раз запускается конструктор пустого класса.

Этот тест показывает незнание работы компилятора и среды исполнения. В С++ кода будет утечка, в шарповом - нет, так как GC все подчистит. Это уже первый звоночек, что тесты не  равнозначные. Добавили хотя бы вызов деструктора. (Но тесты показывают, что это  не сильно ускорит процесс).

НО! в шарповом коде по факту количество выделенной памяти не будет увеличиваться - объект будет уничтожаться, а новый помещаться в старую память. Так как объект пустой, инициализация будет быстрая. Плюс память уже выделена. Формально - присваивание пары указателей + memset().

Но jit оптимизатор может увидеть, что объект хоть и создается, но не используется, а конструктор пустой и выбросить. И по факту - гонять пустой цикл. Хотя в идеале может потом и его выбросить. Но это нужно смотреть отдельно.

Я не настолько силен в C#, но думаю, что если начать выводить адрес объекта, который создается, то он будет постоянно одним и тем же (либо там будет десяток различных адресов, которые в цикле перебираются).

То есть, по факту, с++ код выглядел где то так (очень сильно упрощенный код, на коленке):

```
Foo * f; // это глобальная переменная.

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // это как бы конструктор
    Foo * t;
    if (f == NULL) // если нет объекта, создадим
       t = alloc_memery();
       init(t);
    else {
       t = f;
       init(t); // а это часть конструктора. Память то уже выделена, нам только поля поправить. 
       f = NULL; // объект мы забрали
    }
    // а это деструктор.
    f = t; // вернули объект назад.
    t = NULL;
}
```

Получился такой себе пул объектов на один объект.

Но можно сделать лучше, что как раз и сделает тесты более правильными.

```
char * t = new char[1000]; // выделим себе немножко памяти.
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    new (t) Foo(); // видите странный оператор new?:)
}
delete[] t;
```

(оператор new, который в коде - это такая специальная форма, называется [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)).
Самое интересное - теперь утечки нет, и код работает в раз 10 быстрее оригинала. Я считаю этот код максимально правдоподобным аналогом шарпового кода. Но с другой стороны, можно написать ещё красивее

```
for (int i = 0; i<10000000; i++)
   Foo f(); // да, здесь будет создаваться объект и вызываться конструктор-деструктор
```

не удивлюсь, если шарповый оптимизатор также сделал в оригинальном коде выделения памяти на стеке (это возможно, я точно знаю, что 7 java так умеет). А выделение память на стеке очень дешевое в плане скорости.

Кто то скажет, во в C# прям взял написал и оно быстро, а в С++ нужно ещё что то добавлять. Но в С++ "хаки" делаются легко и не принужденно, а в C# можно быстро напороться на препятствия (да, я знаю об Unsafe коде). Но приведенный выше код я хаком не считаю. И я скорее всего не буду создавать с помощью new миллионы объектов в цикле. А если и понадобиться, то сделаю преаллокацию на нужное кол-во объектов. И это будет быстрее.

Comment: Это лишний ответ. Даже голосовать не буду. @VladD как раз и делал бенчмарк, чтобы показать, что разница **уже в модели распределения памяти**. Как при этом вырождается этот цикл в `C#` уже не имеет ни какого значения. Разницу посчитали, она заполнила пробел первых тестов и это - главное.

Comment: Я сознательно допустил memory leak, чтобы избежать вызовов деструкторов в C++. (Мой последний комментарий к ответу именно это и говорит.) Я хочу померить только 10 миллионов конструкторов + аллокаций памяти на куче. Объекты не удаляются (ну или в C# удаляются сборкой мусора). То, что объекты и вправду создаются, легко проверить, убрав вызов конструктора в цикле.

Comment: при 10kk объектов momory leak уже играет роль.
В Вашем примере с++ было 10миллионов аллокаций+инициализаций. в шарповом - 1-2 аллокации, 10миллионов инициализаций.

@mega - это не ответ, это просто комментарий:) а я хотел показать, что тест очень надуманный и ничего не объясняет в исходном вопросе.

Comment: @KoVadim: целью конкретно этого теста была проверка скорости аллокации. Вы можете чем-то подкрепить своё утверждение о том, что в моём шарповом коде на происходит 10М аллокаций? Если вы можете предложить лучший тест, который проверяет лишь скорость аллокации (!), я с удовольствием пересмотрел бы свои результаты. Не согласен тем, что placement new -- корректный аналог: в нём аллокации памяти _вообще_ не происходит.

Comment: Просто создайте List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>(); и потом добавляйте в него в цикле созданный объект.

Comment: @KoVadim: не совсем, тут происходит обновление списка, которое тоже небесплатно. Плюс, обращение к списку нарушает локальность кеша.

Comment: Если _внимательно_ посмотреть на мои примеры, то можно увидеть что
1. Оптимизация как в примерах @VladD не сработает, ибо кладем все в массив.
2. Сборка мусора также не сработает, и если это не очевидно то убедиться можно сравнив http://pastebin.com/FqNYLrXm и http://pastebin.com/4Nv1kdEh
Не будет оверхеда как со списком, с кешем будут одинаковые промахи в обоих языках.

Раз уж скорость лучезарного сишарпа здесь важнее здравого смысла и желания добраться до сути, то мне остается только удалиться из дискуссии.

Comment: >это не ответ, это просто комментарий

За этот якобы не ответ, максимум, что Вы заслуживаете - минус, поскольку пытаетесь запутать участников.

>а я хотел показать, что тест очень надуманный и ничего не объясняет в исходном вопросе.

Тест как раз все и объясняет, поскольку в исходном алгоритме не важно, какие операции идут ниже оператора `new`, они на этот алгоритм не влияют, поэтому, для чистоты эксперимента следовало исключить время, которое он занимал в аналогичных условиях с обоих сторон, что и было сделано обоими участниками: @VladD и @Dith. (Что "чистота" его сомнительна и так всем ясно