# Поиск по члену структуры?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры-данных

```
struct S
{
int a;
double b;
std::string c;
};
```

Нужно найти те структуры где a=5 и с="orange". Главное: скорость поиска, вставки и удаления структуры.

1. Есть ли структуры данных под такую задачу, которые бы гарантировали логарифмическое время поиска? Или только прямой обход?
2. Если нет, то как лучше решить подобную проблему? Вроде микро субд, которые в оперативной памяти бы только работали и предоставляли минимум функций, *SELECT WHERE 'a'=5 AND 'c'="orange"*

---

Наверное меня не совсем поняли или неправильно показал.
Вот посмотрите на это, будет ли подобный поиск безопасным, или выдаст исключение что operator< не корректный?
За счёт использования глобальной переменной состояния управлять поиском в глобальной же переменной контейнере. Ясно, что такое решение не будет потокобезопасным.
При вставке в контейнер, структура уникальна учитывая все ключи-члены, но при других вариантах поиска, учитываются только некоторые ключи члены.

```
bool поиск_вида_1 = true;  // ищем по всем ключам
bool поиск_вида_2 = false; // ищем по переменной a
bool поиск_вида_3 = false; // ищем по переменной a и с

struct S
{
int a;
double b;
std::string c;

// Все члены структуры в ключе
bool operator<(S const & ss) const;
};


bool S::operator<(S const & ss) const
{

if(поиск_вида_1)
{
if ( a != ss.a) return a < ss.a;
if ( b != ss.b) return b < ss.b; 
if ( c != ss.c) return c < ss.c; 
}

if(поиск_вида_2)
{
if ( a != ss.a) return a < ss.a;
}

if(поиск_вида_3)
{
if ( a != ss.a) return a < ss.a;
if ( c != ss.c) return c < ss.c; 
}

return false; 
}


int main()
{
std::map<S , int> map__;

поиск_вида_1=true;

{
S ss1;
ss1.a=1;
ss1.b=100;
ss1.c="orange";
map__[ss1]=10;
}

{
S ss1;
ss1.a=2;
ss1.b=200;
ss1.c="apple";
map__[ss1]=20;
}

{
S ss1;
ss1.a=2;
ss1.b=300;
ss1.c="apple";
map__[ss1]=30;
}

{
S ss1;
ss1.a=2;
ss1.b=300;
ss1.c="apple2";
map__[ss1]=40;
}

поиск_вида_1=false;

поиск_вида_2=true;

// Вот здесь нужно найти есть ли структуры где a==2.
S ss2;
ss2.a=2;
//ss2.b=300;
//ss2.c="apple";
std::cout << "\nmap=" << map__.count(ss2);

поиск_вида_2=false;

поиск_вида_3=true;

// Вот здесь нужно найти есть ли структуры где a==2 и с=="apple"
S ss3;
ss3.a=2;
//ss3.b=300;
ss3.c="apple";
std::cout << "\nmap=" << map__.count(ss3);

поиск_вида_3=false;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::unordered_set` имеет O(1) по поиску, вставке и удалению. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Есть ли структуры данных под такую задачу, которые бы гарантировали логарифмическое время поиска? Или только прямой обход?

Ну смотрите: математически, за логарифм умеет искать только бинарный поиск => нужно чтобы элементы были отсортированы => нужно либо задать правило сортировки (`bool operator<(...)`) и отсортировать массив, либо задать правило сортировки и использовать для хранения элементов упорядочивающий контейнер (map/set).

Если в этом же массиве требуется искать элементы по ключу, по которому массив не был изначально отсортирован, то сделать это за логарифм никак не удастся.

> 2. Если нет, то как лучше решить подобную проблему? Вроде микро субд, которые в оперативной памяти бы только работали и предоставляли минимум функций, SELECT WHERE 'a'=5 AND 'c'="orange"

Тут, как всегда в задачках на сортировку, только 2 решения. Выбирать можно то, которое лучше ложиться на архитектуру проекта.
1) Решение за счет памяти: рисуем "супер" класс BigS, который содержит в себе 3 варианта массива структур S, каждая из которых отсортирована по своему закону. Вставка/удаление реализуются через `BigS::insert()/BigS::erase()` каждая из которых вставляет/удаляет из 3 массивов.
2) Решение за счет процессора. Держим в классе BigS один массив структур, и флаг - по какому конкретно закону в данный момент отсортирован массив. Функция `BigS::count(elem, SORT_BY_A)` будет принимать флаг и анализировать его: если вызывающий код попросил элемент по ключу `a` и массив в данный момент отсортирован по `a`, то обычным std::find() в контейнере выдаем результат. Если массив в данный момент отсортирован по другому закону, то пересортировавыем на лету и после этого ищем.

Также, стандартный способ оптимизации таких задач - кеш "горячих" данных. Кеш в том или ином виде можно прикрутить как к первому, так и ко второму варианту.
С другой стороны, если описание вопроса полностью отражает необходимость, а не является только лишь примером - демонстрацией проблемы, то есть, искать требуется именно в такой структуре, и кроме того не по любому ключу, а только по `a` или по составному ключу `a,c`, то в данном случае можно обойтись одной копией данных, упорядоченной по `(a,c)`.

Comment: Ещё хэш-таблица. То есть она гарантирует O(1), но может и за O(log n), если ещё бесплатно прокрутит холостой цикл

Comment: Зачем нужны три варианта сортировки, если все ключи связаны между собой отношением вложенности?

Comment: @VladD, да, в качестве контейнеров можно использовать хеши. Иногда они дают хороший прирост в производительности. Тогда в варианте **за счет памяти** держим 3 unordered_map, а вот вариант **за счет cpu**..не знаю, кажется на него хеш-таблица не ложится

Comment: @Shamov, отношением вложенности-то они связаны, но это отношение не позволяет выполнять поиск по любому из ключей за логарифмическое время. Три варианта сортированных данных - именно чтобы искать за логарифм по любому из нужных ключей. Фактически - это, как говорилось выше, имитация реляционной БД, в которой каждый ключ представляет собой копию тех же данных, но отсортированную по-своему.

Comment: @o2gy Как это не позволяет? Как раз именно за счёт вложенности ключей несколько типов поиска могут обойтись одним и тем же индексом, сохранив логарифмическое время поиска.

Comment: @o2gy А вот как раз хэш-таблица и unordered-структуры не подходят для этой задачи вообще. Даже при условии, что их будет 3 штуки. Можно сделать и с их помощью, но они здесь просто не к месту.

Comment: А точно нельзя обойтись 1 сортирующим контейнером (std::map)?

Вот в том коде обновленном что я показал, там ведь дерево заполняется полным ключом. Если в контейнер что то вставлять еще, с "другим" измененным operator< то тогда дерево должно биться, из-за того что оно больше не линейное упорядоченное множество. Но если выполнять поиск в нём(методы count(), find()), то ведь проход по узлам дерева должен быть безопасным, так как каждый узел просматривается и ищутся узлы соответствующие запросу, которые внутри дерева уже есть, то есть отсеиваются все узлы, которые не соответствуют запросу.

Comment: -------------------------
Тогда функция count() в map может выдать много значений, а не 1, иначе бы функция count() была бессмысленна в map, как можно посчитать количество узлов с таким ключом, если допускается только 1 уникальный ключ?

Comment: @manking Обойтись одним контейнером точно можно. Благодаря тому, что ключи для всех видов поиска образуют единую цепочку вложенности. Правда с функцией `count` это никак не связано. Она имеет смысл даже тогда, когда возвращает 0 или 1.

Comment: @Shamov, а давайте я приведу контрпример.

Comment: @Shamov, Зададим несколько элементов типа: `S s1(1, 5.5, "mama"), s2(1, 10.5, "mamam")`, s3(1, 15.5, "papa"), s4(1, 20.5, "papa"), s5(2, 2, "a")`. В соответствии с правилом сортировки из примера - поиск_вида_1 - они так и расположатся в порядке s1-s5. Теперь мы хотим в этом множестве найти элемент, у которого последняя часть ключа == "a". Либо тут это все таки невозможно сделать за логарифм, либо мы друг друга неверно понимаем, либо не понимаем задачу :)

Comment: @manking, одним сортирующим контейнером, в общем случае, обойтись нельзя, по причинам, которые я указал выше (и даже привел пример). Вы и сами интуитивно это понимаете - раз в вопросе провели аналогию с БД.

Comment: @o2gy Это не контрпример. Просто в этом случае правило сортировки должно быть другим. Если нужно искать по последней части ключа, то и сортировать нужно от конца к началу: сначала по последней части ключа, затем по предпоследней и т.д.

Comment: @Shamov, именно! Я так понял, что автор хочет "все и сразу", то есть иметь один составной индекс, и при этом быстро искать по подиндексам. Но это невозможно.

Comment: @o2gy Это возможно при условии, что каждый подключ является вложенным во все другие ключи, имеющие больше полей. В примере автора это условие соблюдается. Вы удивитесь, но в БД в таких случаях тоже используется один индекс для поиска по любой части ключа.

Comment: @Shamov, хорошо, вот еще пример, из мускуля:

Comment: @o2gy Где? Уже 5 минут никакого примера нет.

Comment: @Shamov,    mysql> show create table blabla;<br/>`CREATE TABLE `blabla` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,...  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), KEY `UEmail` (`UserEmail`)
  KEY `UserEmail` (`UserEmail`,`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4892 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 PACK_KEYS=1`<br/> Вроде как наличие составного ключа не мешает мускулю также иметь ключи по каждому полю отдельно.<br/> Я, кстати, согласен, что иногда - для решения задачи от автора - можно обойтись одним ключом - когда подключи упорядоченны в составе общего ключа. Но мне кажется, что в задаче автора это условие не выполняется.

Comment: Не понимаю, как красиво редактировать комментарии :(

Comment: @o2gy В этой схеме ключ `UEmail` просто избыточен. Попробуйте его удалить. Скорость поиска по единственному полю `UserEmail` останется прежней.

Comment: @o2gy В задаче автора требуемое условие выполняется. Просто ключи упорядочены не по номеру поля в структуре, а чуть-чуть иначе. Сортировать нужно по (a, с, b). В моём втором ответе делается именно так. Любой ключ, используемый для поиска, является вложенным во все более длинные ключи, поэтому достаточно одного индекса.

Comment: @Shamov, в этой - да, избыточен. Я его просто добавил, чтобы убедится, что mysql это позволяет. Если есть составной ключ (ID, Email), то поиск чисто по ID в таком ключе будет настолько же быстрый, как если бы мы имели ключ только по ID и искали бы в нем. А вот, чтобы быстро искать по Email, нужен отдельный ключ - Email. Если составной ключ будет из 3 полей(ID1, ID2, ID3), то для быстрого поиска по каждому полю все же придется заводить ключи ID2 и ID3.

Comment: @Shamov, но я наконец все же соглашаюсь, что в данном случае Вы правы! Почитав внимательнее условие, я увидел, что поле b не учитывается, и искать отдельно по c и отдельно по b тут вроде как не требуется. Отредактирую свой ответ.

Comment: @o2gy Ура! Наконец-то! :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23533/discussion-on-answer-by-o2gy----).

Answer (score 2):

В качестве структуры для индекса подойдёт обычная `std::map`. Тот факт, что ключ для поиска составной, решительно ничего не меняет. В современном С++ для работы с составными значениями существует тип `std::tuple`. И он идеально подходит в качестве ключа, поскольку как раз реализует операцию "меньше чем", необходимую для сортировки структур.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;
};

class container_for_S : vector<S> {
public:
    void insert(S&& s) {
        auto it = index.find(tie(s.a, s.c));
        if (it == index.end()) {
            emplace_back(s);
            index.insert(make_pair(tie(back().a, back().c), ref(back())));
        }
        else
            it->second.b = s.b;
    }

    double find(int a, string c) {
        auto it = index.find(tie(a, c));
        return it != index.end() ? it->second.b : 0.0;
    }

private:
    map<tuple<int&, string&>, S&> index;
};

int main()
{
    container_for_S cont;
    cont.insert({1, 1.0, "red"});
    cont.insert({2, 2.0, "green"});
    cont.insert({3, 3.0, "blue"});
    cont.insert({4, 4.0, "white"});
    cont.insert({5, 5.0, "orange"});

    cout << cont.find(5, "orange") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не проще было лямбду просто передать в конструктор `std::map`, которая сравнение производит? Кстати, наследовать стандартные структуру данных не рекомендуется.

Comment: @ixSci Подлинный смысл ответа не в том, чтобы решить конкретную проблему, а в том, чтобы полнее раскрыть тему составных значений. А наследование приватное, поэтому ничего страшного.

Comment: @ixSci Я подумал насчёт лямбды и не понял, каким образом она решит проблему. Проблема ведь не в том, чтобы сделать нестандартное сравнение, а в том, чтобы синтезировать отсутствующий ключ.

Comment: не понял насчёт "отсутствующего ключа". Насколько я понимаю вопрос, автор просто хочет быстро искать структура по нескольким полям, вот и всё.

Comment: @ixSci Да, именно так его понял и я. Но для поиска в `std::map` нужно иметь ключ, которого изначально нет.

Comment: Я имел ввиду такое: http://ideone.com/3yFpmD

Comment: @ixSci Теперь понятно. Разумеется, при использовании `std::set` нет проблемы отсутствующего ключа, поскольку само значение является ключом.

Comment: @Abyx Согласен. Но оставим необходимую модификацию кода автору вопроса в качестве упражнения.

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, поиск в `std::map` медленнее, чем в `std::unordered_map` (и имеет асимптотику имеет `O(log n)` против амортизированного `O(n)` в `std::unordered_map`). ЗЫ: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/190095/10105) есть бенчмарки (но только на добавление).

Comment: @VladD Он не медленнее, чем требуется в вопросе. Но гораздо важнее то, что `unordered_map` вообще нельзя использовать. Внутри неё хэш-таблица, которая требует, чтобы для элементов была определена операция "не равно". Что нельзя обеспечить из-за наличия в структуре поля с типом `double`.

Comment: @VladD И, кстати, `O(log n)` лучше, чем `O(n)`. Но не в этом суть. Правильная асимптотика для поиска по `unordered_map` - `O(1)`, и она действительно лучше, чем `O(log n)`.

Comment: @Shamov: Ой, да. Очепятка.

Comment: @Shamov: Если так, по той же причине (`double`) тогда нельзя и `std::map` использовать.

Comment: @VladD Во-первых, можно, потому что поле типа `double` не входит в ключ. Во-вторых, можно было бы, даже если бы оно входило, потому что внутри `map` сортирующее дерево. Оно требует всего лишь операции "меньше чем", которая для типа `double` определена.

Comment: @Shamov: Всё равно, а при поиске? Как проверять равенство?

Comment: @VladD Не понял вопрос. Зачем при поиске по дереву проверять равенство?

Comment: @Shamov: Ну, ровно по той же причине, что и в `unordered_map`. Мне кажется, любой аргумент для `unordered_map` переносится на `map`.

Comment: @VladD Каким образом он переносится, если эти структуры устроены абсолютно по-разному? Более того, само существование двух этих структур обусловлено тем, что иногда есть операция "равно", и хочется выжать из этого максимум, а иногда есть только операция "меньше чем", и тогда приходится работать с ней.

Comment: @Shamov: Окей, давайте попробуем. Для чего в `unordered_map` операция сравнения не по ключу?

Comment: @VladD Ни для чего. В `unordered_map` операция сравнения не используется вообще. В ней используется операция сопоставления. Она применяется к ключу для разрешения коллизий, которые возможны при вычислении хэша.

Comment: @Shamov: Получается, `unordered_map` при работе с рассматриваемой структурой не будет сравнивать `double`?

Comment: @VladD Смотря о какой из рассматриваемых структур идёт речь. Если говорить о начальном варианте вопроса, то у меня было ощущение, что `double` не является частью ключа. Можно было дополнительно определить операцию сопоставления так, чтобы `double` не участвовал. Однако обновление вопроса перевернуло всё с ног на голову. Теперь похоже, что ключом является вся структура.

Comment: @Shamov: Ох, не заметил обновления. В начальном варианте ключ и его хэшкод считался не затрагивая `double`, так что проблем ИМХО не должно было бы быть. Почитаю обновление...

Comment: @VladD Против этого не возражаю. Без `double` в ключе можно было исхитриться так, чтобы задействовать `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 2):

После обновления вопрос превратился в совершенно другой. Теперь задача выглядит так, как будто ключом является вся структура целиком, и нужен всего лишь поиск по частичному ключу. С одной стороны, это проще, поскольку синтезировать ключ при помощи `std::tuple` не потребуется. С другой стороны, решение более длинное, поскольку для каждого вида поиска потребуется сделать отдельную функцию.

```
#include <map>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;

    bool operator <(const S& rhs) const {
        if (a < rhs.a) return true; else if (rhs.a < a) return false;
        if (c < rhs.c) return true; else if (rhs.c < c) return false;
        return b < rhs.b;
    }

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& stm, const S& rhs);
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& stm, const S& rhs) {
    return stm << "(" << rhs.a << ", "
               << fixed << setprecision(1) << rhs.b << ", "
               << rhs.c << ")";
}

map<S, int> index;

void find(int a, double b, string c) {
    auto it = index.find(S{a, b, c});
    if (it != end(index))
        cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void find(int a, string c) {
    auto it = index.lower_bound(S{a, numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), c});
    while (it != end(index) && it->first.a == a && it->first.c == c) {
        cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;
        it++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void find(int a) {
    auto it = index.lower_bound(S{a, numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), ""});
    while (it != end(index) && it->first.a == a) {
        cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;
        it++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    index.emplace(S{1, 1.1, "red"}, 1001);
    index.emplace(S{2, 2.1, "green"}, 1002);
    index.emplace(S{3, 3.1, "blue"}, 1003);
    index.emplace(S{4, 4.1, "white"}, 1004);
    index.emplace(S{5, 5.1, "orange"}, 1005);

    index.emplace(S{1, 1.2, "red"}, 1006);
    index.emplace(S{2, 2.2, "green"}, 1007);
    index.emplace(S{3, 3.2, "blue"}, 1008);
    index.emplace(S{4, 4.2, "white"}, 1009);
    index.emplace(S{5, 5.2, "orange"}, 1010);

    index.emplace(S{1, 1.3, "not red"}, 1011);
    index.emplace(S{2, 2.3, "not green"}, 1012);
    index.emplace(S{3, 3.3, "not blue"}, 1013);
    index.emplace(S{4, 4.3, "not white"}, 1014);
    index.emplace(S{5, 5.3, "not orange"}, 1015);

    find(5, 5.1, "orange");
    find(5, "orange");
    find(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать хэш-контейнер (`std::unordered_set, std::unordered_map`), где хэш будет считаться по композитному ключу (a, c). Имея хорошую хэш функцию производительность будет на уровне.

---

Ответ на обновление: в общем виде, без дублирования, задача не решается с требуемыми параметрами. Если бы она решалась, то не было бы нужды в индексах БД. А они есть. Так вот, если требования к памяти не критичны, то можно на каждое условие завести по `std::unordered_set/std::set` и использовать тот или иной объект, в зависимости от условия.

Но проще всего, на мой взгляд, переложить это всё на БД и не морочить себе голову.