# C++ vector<pair> или unordered_map?

Tags: c++, vector

Что предпочтительнее использовать для хранения довольно большого количества элементов(простые типы)?
`vector<pair<>>` или `unordered_map`?
И есть ли что производительнее, чем `vector` для хранения одномерного списка? Везде вижу, что заместо array при динамическом кол-ве элементов используют именно `vector`.

В случае одномерного списка нужно быстро добавлять и удалять. И искать значение через указатель на ячейку памяти. В случае двумерного списка нужно искать второе значение по первому, добавлять, удалять.

Comment: Эти контейнеры обладают разными свойствами. Как ты их вот так просто взял и сравнил по производительности? Да и вообще, какую цель ты преследуешь?

Comment: Ок. Большие объемы простых данных. В том числе указателей.
Никакой "схлопываемости" при удалении элементов.
Нужен одномерный и двумерный тип списков. Быстрый поиск элемента по ключу в случае двумерности.

Comment: Немного не понял, а как поиск по ключу связан с vector?

Comment: vector<pair<Key,Value>>. Прошу прощения, если не понятно, я в C++ после C#. Там есть словари.

Comment: а что нужно? быстро читать или быстро добавлять/удалять?

Comment: @rinart73, и как в таком случае найти значение по ключу?

Comment: Вот тут есть не худший алгоритм выбора контейнера: http://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/194726/

Comment: В случае одномерного списка нужно быстро добавлять и удалять. И искать значение через указатель на ячейку памяти.
В случае двумерного списка нужно искать второе значение по первому, добавлять, удалять.

Comment: @rinart73: Это важное уточнение, так что имеет смысл внести его в вопрос. После этого вопрос становится осмысленным.

Comment: Что значит "искать значение через указатель на ячейку памяти" ?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно быстрое добавление и удаление, возьмите `unordered_set`: у него эти операции — амортизированный O(1). Непонятно, однако, что вы подразумеваете под «искать значение через указатель на ячейку памяти».

Для второго случая вам нужен `unordered_map`, у него та же асимптотика.

---

Для случая `vector<pair<Key, Value>>` у вас поиск, добавление и удаление O(размер контейнера). Для маленьких значений размера это *может* быть скорее за счёт примитивности операций, но со сколько-нибудь большими размерами берите `unordered_*`.

---

Поскольку вы упоминали в комментариях, что пришли из C#: в C++, в отличие от C#, довольно медленный стандартный аллокатор. Поэтому производительность контейнеров [вполне может быть слабее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/189730/10105), чем у аналогичных в C#.

Comment: Я имею ввиду возможность получить указатель на добавленный элемент, для его последующего изменения и получения его значения.

Comment: @rinart73: Ну, [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) возвращает вам итератор на вставленный элемент. Но обратите внимание на тонкости: (1) после вставки следующего элемента итератор (а значит, и указатель на элемент) инвалидируется, им более пользоваться нельзя. (2) _изменять_ элемент по данному итератору/указателю **нельзя**, т. к. вы поменяете хэшкод элемента.

Comment: Но в unordered_set нужно заморачиваться с хешами. Производительность же пострадает опять же...
И какие есть тогда варианты? Как добавлять большое количество элементов, получая указатели на них, которые будут действительны и по которым элементы можно будет менять?
А можно брать не итератор элемента, а именно указатель на ячейку памяти?

Comment: @rinart73: (1) быстрее, чем `unordered_set`, не бывает. Если вам нужно быстрое удаление, лучшего решения, чем хеш-таблица, не придумано. Производительность там O(1), это по-любому лучше, чем O(n) у наивного контейнера.

Comment: @rinart73: (2) Если вам нужно менять элементы, то всё хуже. Потому что если структура заточена под быстрый поиск, то она располагает ваш элемент в себе хитрым образом в зависимости от его значения. Если вы меняете значение, вы обманываете структуру, и получаете закономерный креш.

Comment: @rinart73: (3) Вы не можете держать указатель на элемент хотя бы потому, что сам элемент может перемещаться в памяти при изменении контейнера. Таким образом, любой чих или даже косой взгляд в сторону контейнера превращает ваш указатель в висящий, по которому вы испортите чужую память.

Comment: @rinart73: Разумным компромиссом может быть помещение в структуру не элемента, а указателя на него: `unordered_set<struct data*>`.