# Почему аллокация памяти в языках со сборкой мусора быстрее, чем в языках без них?

Tags: java, c#, c++, память, сборщик-мусора

Уже не первый раз слышу, что скорость аллокации в куче в *C#* или *Java* быстрее, чем в *C++*. Я не могу понять, почему это может быть: аллокация в куче подразумевает поиск свободной страницы в памяти. Как это можно ускорить и правдивы ли слухи?

Comment: "и правдивы ли слухи" - тесты. "как это можно ускорить?" - что ускорить, нет же ничего.

Comment: @DollarDollar, другими словами "что делает сборщик мусора такого что аллокация в куче быстрее"?

Comment: другими словами решайте только существующие проблемы

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Да, эти слухи правдивы и имеют под собой основания.

Дело в том, что в языках наподобие C++ аллокация обычно подразумевает поиск свободного блока в списке свободных блоков. При этом, если программа многопоточная, может понадобиться ещё и глобальная блокировка. После нахождения свободного блока необходимо ещё и скорректировать список свободных блоков, и разместить в выделенном блоке дополнительную информацию.

В языках наподобие C# аллокация намного проще. Для нового элемента память выделяется просто на верху heap-памяти, и таким образом, аллокация сводится к простому

```
Interlocked.Increment(heapPtr, requestedSize);
```

что, конечно, намного быстрее поиска по списку свободных блоков.

В чём же разница? Дело в том, что сборщик мусора в .NET выполняет кроме самой сборки ещё и *уплотнение* кучи (heap compaction): дыры в куче, возникающие на месте собранного мусора, заполняются другими объектами, и все указатели на них сдвигаются. Пример:

Аллоцированные объекты:

```
[ объект №1 ] [ объект №2     ] [ о. №3 ] [ о. №4                ] [ о. №5     ]
                                                                                ^
                                                                                |
                                                                             heapptr
```

Первая фаза сборки мусора (собраны объекты №1 и №4):

```
              [ объект №2     ] [ о. №3 ]                          [ о. №5     ]
                                                                                ^
                                                                                |
                                                                             heapptr
```

Уплотнение:

```
[ объект №2     ] [ о. №3 ] [ о. №5     ]
                                         ^
                                         |
                                      heapptr
```

В результате, рантайм может аллоцировать новые объекты всегда на верху кучи, не боясь того, что дыры в куче займут слишком много места.

В C++ нет надёжного способа определить, где находятся указатели на данный объект, поэтому трюк с уплотнением кучи невозможен.

---

Однако же, C++ (в отдельных случаях) вполне может ускорить аллокации за счёт *кастомных* аллокаторов, которые могут затребовать сразу большой кусок памяти у рантайма, и раздавать его объектам.

---

На самом деле сборка мусора сложнее, чем я описал. [Вот тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/automatic-memory-management), например, есть начальные сведения о том, как происходит сборка мусора в .NET.

Comment: *компактификация* это общепринятый перевод *compaction*? Или нет? Я б склонялся к переводу "укладка", "укладывание", или чему-то похожему. А то "компактификация" даже выговорить непросто :) И ещё подброшу [ссылку с забавными анимациями разных GC](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/09/03/visualizing-garbage-collection-algorithms/).

Comment: @VladD, если только лишь в конце добавлять, то, выходит, адрес легко получить используя просто арифметику указателей(прибавить 1), это ж  сравнимо со скоростью аллокации на стеке получается... тогда как вообще джава и сишарп могут плюсам по скорости проигрывать, если работа с памятью такая быстрая

Comment: Интересно, если при сборке мусора не использовать дополнительную память для сортировок, то в целом (так сказать, "на круг") какой метод предпочтительней? Я понимаю, что каждое выделение памяти по запросу в шарпе быстрое, а  вот общее к-во циклов процессора (с учетом периодической сборки мусора)?

Comment: @D-side: Хм, может, лучше «упаковка»?

Comment: @xperious: Так и есть — скорость аллокации объектов на куче и на стеке в .NET вполне сравнимы. Проигрыш по скорости может быть из-за всяческих проверок: например, в C# при доступе к элементу массива проверяется выход индекса за границы диапазона, а в C++ нет. Ну и JIT-компиляция может быть не настолько эффективной (хотя её эффективность постоянно улучшают).

Comment: @xperious: Вот, кстати, старый вопрос по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/189730/10105

Comment: @VladD по мне так это менее удачный вариант. "Укладываются" обычно какие-то вещи поплотнее, а "упаковываются" обычно вещи в упаковку, которая таскается целиком. Смысловой конфликт с архивацией и подобными вещами.

Comment: @avp: Лучше всего, думаю, кастомный аллокатор, который берёт память куском, и возвращает тоже куском. А о какой дополнительной памяти вы говорите?

Comment: @D-side: Майкрософтовская документация называет это «уплотнением»: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/automatic-memory-management

Comment: @VladD о, тоже неплохой вариант. И ещё у первого упоминания стоит в скобочках обозначить исходный вариант на английском. На всякий случай :)

Comment: @VladD, вообще благодарствую за простое объяснение... понятно стало сразу,  но в реальности, я так понимаю, все сложнее... про аллокацию имею ввиду

Comment: @xperious: Пожалуйста, рад, что смог хорошо объяснить! В реальности сборка мусора сложнее. Есть несколько поколений (для ускорения). Есть объекты с финализатором, их нужно отдельно обработать. Есть неперемещаемые объекты, их нужно обходить. И т. д.

Comment: @VladD, в рихтере есть про сборщик мусора в .net? а то нету под рукой

Comment: @xperious: По идее, обязано быть, это ж Рихтер!

Comment: @avp я сравнивал сортировки слиянием с выделением памяти по необходимости и по размеру входных данных. Второй вариант оказался производительнее и менее затратен по дополнительной памяти независимо от длины входного массива, если вы об этом.

Comment: @VladD, `о какой дополнительной памяти вы говорите?` --  о той, которая может понадобится для эффективной сборки мусора.

Comment: @avp: Окей, понял. Ну мне кажется, это зависит от программы и количества свободной памяти (чтобы не грузить paging). Например, для утилиты командной строки без циклов часто имеет смысл вовсе не собирать мусор. С другой стороны, сборщики мусора становятся всё умнее, делят объекты на поколения для эффективной работы и всё такое.

Comment: @avp: Да, если посмотреть на типичную программу, то она не грузит процессор на все 100% всё время. Это значит, что для сборки мусора можно выделить время, когда процессор простаивает. Нагрузка на аллокацию/деаллокацию, напротив, наибольшая именно тогда, когда программа активно работает, так что подход без GC тут в минусе. (Представьте себе освобождение последней ссылки на корень дерева объектов, и каскад деструкторов, который это запускает.)